# Print Lines That Are Greater Than Two Fields

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

I'm okay with `grep`, but I know that `awk` is probably way more efficient in this case. I'm learning but not quite there yet.

I have some data:

```
record1,14.2,10,50
record2,10.7,5,-
record3,9.3,6.8,10
record4,8,2.7,10
record5,5.5,22.4,10
record6,3,23.6,55
record7,2.7,14.6,-
```

I would like to print only the lines that are greater than greater than 7 in field 3 and greater than 10 (while removing any dashs) in field 4. Thus, the output would be this:

```
record1,14.2,10,50
record6,3,23.6,55
```

I have played around using `awk '{print $3 > 7}'`, however, like i said, I'm not great with `awk` and conditions. I could do it with grep but I feel like that's inefficient. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of an awk script is `condition { action }`. The default action is `{ print }`, which prints the whole record.

- Your conditions are `$3 > 7` and `$4 > 10`.
- Your field separator is a comma.

Combining those things we get:

```
awk -F, '$3 > 7 && $4 > 10' file
```